# No token field in the docs test page for /me/reputation-history

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, api-v2.1

There is no form field for an *access token* at:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-reputation-history
- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history

After attempting to *Run* the API method from either page:

```
{
    "error_id": 401,
    "error_name": "access_token_required",
    "error_message": "This method requires an access_token"
}
```

The */users* versions have the field:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history
- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.